# Loop a bitmap array in android java?

Tags: java, android

I have a bitmap array:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

I add items on it using this:

```
bitmapArray.add(bitmap);
```

I'd like to loop this array, so I tried:

```
 for (int i=0; i < bitmapArray.lenght; i++) { // cannot resolve symbol length

 }
```

the length gives me the cannot resolve symbol length. I also try size() instead of length but it is not entering in for even if I have items. Any ideas how can I loop my bitmap array?

Thanks.

Comment: ...`bitmapArray.size()`

Comment: @YCF_L and do you know why i cannot enter inside for? even if I have items?

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(bitmapArray.size())`?

Comment: It looks like you may have typed code into your question rather than copy/paste from the actual source. Please always copy/paste so we are looking at the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bitmapArray.size()`. ArrayList don't have length property.